# Fast cosine similarity for sparse vectors

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy

I have Pandas dataframe that has one column with sparse vectors on each row.
The dataframe also has an index with string id of each vector.
My goal is to compute cosine_similarity of a given vector (input is vector id) and all other vectors.

```
import scipy
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

cosine_similarity(df.at[input_id, 'vector'],  scipy.sparse.vstack(df['vector'].values))
```

This code works, however it's very slow, mostly because of vstack.
What can I do to make this work faster? I don't mind changing the dataframe format and/or even dropping pandas is favor of raw numpy if this gonna help.

Dataframe structure:

```
>df['vector'].values

array([<1x90000 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float32'>'
    with 55 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
       <1x90000 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float32'>'
    with 54 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
       <1x90000 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float32'>'
    with 78 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
       ...,
       <1x90000 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float32'>'
    with 37 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
       <1x90000 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float32'>'
    with 78 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
       <1x90000 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float32'>'
    with 82 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>], dtype=object)
```

Comment: `sparse.vstack` combines the `coo` attributes of all those matrices into one set of attributes, makes the new matrix from those.  It's a robust general mechanism, but not particularly efficient.  But I think the only alternative is to construct the multirow matrix 'from-scratch' rather than making a lot of one-row ones.

Comment: @hpaulj I thought about this, but it's not clear how to "attach" string index with ids to such matrix.